# How to read all the text from a file in C

Tags: c, readfile

I want to read all the text in the file.txt. I want 1 line code that can read all. I used this before this:`while(!feof(Fpointer))` But this didn't work

What should I do next?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    float day, ask;
    char add[69];
        char line[255];

    FILE*Fpointer=fopen("Wano.txt", "a+");
    printf("\nDo you want to add new task?");
    scanf("%f",&ask);   
        
    if(ask<=1)
    {
        FILE*Fpointer=fopen("Wano.txt", "a");
        printf( "Enter Your Task  : ");
        fscanf(stdin, "\n %s", add);
        fprintf(Fpointer, "\n");  // newline here

        fputs(add, Fpointer);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        Fpointer=fopen("Wano.txt", "r");
        fgets(line, 255, Fpointer);
        puts(line);
        fgets(line, 255, Fpointer);
        puts(line);
        fgets(line, 255, Fpointer);
        puts(line);
    
}
    else
    printf("\nFailed");
}
```

`

Comment: "I want 1 line code that can read all." - Then don't program in C.

Comment: `while(fgetch(Fpointer) != EOF);` will _read_ the entire file in one line.  Yet I suspect you want to do more than read an entire file.  What is the goal after reading?

Comment: You don't close the file after first open and write. It probably means, data is not written to it when you open it again and read from it.

Comment: _... But this didn't work_ - please be more specific. See [ask]

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\nFailed");`  in general, should end printf() format strings with `'\n'  so the data will be immediately output

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int c=getchar(); c != EOF && putchar(c) != EOF; c=getchar());
```

Although you have to arrange that *stdin* and *stdout* are the right files; so assuming you have two `FILE *`: infile, outfile:

```
 for (int c=getc(infile); c!=EOF && putc(c, outfile) != EOF; c=getc(infile));
```

Comment: I have worked in commercial software development, mainly in C and assembly,  for about 45 years.  I have never used `feof` for anything.   It is a somewhat broken concept inspired by Pascal's broken i/o model.  That should be on the manual page.  Stdio is for portable; if you want robust, use open,close,read,write.  Atrocities like `feof, ferror, ...` may work on some systems, or not.

Answer (score -1):

To read whole file in one line (Why?)

```
char line[1024] = {0};
size_t len = 0;
size_t l = 0;
FILE* Fpointer = fopen("Wano.txt", "a+b");
while ((l = fread(line + len, 1, 1024 - len, Fpointer)) && (len += l));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243538/discussion-on-answer-by-vikram-how-to-read-all-the-text-from-a-file-in-c).